# c# Append result of Dictionary Replacement

Tags: c#, string, dictionary, replace

I have a dictionary containing a `key` for abbreviated words and a `value` the full meaning. this is named `WordDictionary`held in a class named `fileParser`.

I am trying to append an abbreviated words full meaning with in a string. I can find and replace the word with the full meaning but is there a way in which the full meaning can be appended after the abbreviated word as follows.

> some text with the abbreviation LOL

would be changed to.

> some text with the abbreviation LOL (Laughing Out Loud)

The code I have to replace the abbreviation is as follows.

```
foreach (string s in isInFile)
            {
                StringBuilder expandedTXT = new StringBuilder(inMessage);
                //test for reading words from TB 
                //Console.WriteLine(s);
                if (fileParser.IsWordAvailable(s))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(s);// displays word checked in console
                    foreach(var word in fileParser.WordDictionary)
                    {
                        expandedTXT.Replace(word.Key, word.Value);
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show("Match found: " + s);
                    MessageBox.Show("New String: " + expandedTXT.ToString());
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace the value with whatever you want, it is not necessary to use just value of a single variable. I.e. you can construct the desired substring from the abbreviation and full meaning using string concatenation or preferably formatting:

```
  expandedTXT.Replace(word.Key, 
        String.Format("{0} ({1})", word.Key, word.Value));
```